# iOS simulator slowing osx down and interfering with magic mouse

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, magic-mouse

Has anyone noticed that when using iOS simulator for extended periods of time or during launch of Apps that there is a disturbance in the performance of osx and the magic mouse?

The other day a darkened view loading across the osx screen and it said I needed to restart.

These are the logs for my app from the console - there are stacks more though:

```
0x954c7000 - 0x954cafe7  libmathCommon.A.dylib 315.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <1622A54F-1A98-2CBE-B6A4-2122981A500E> /usr/lib/system/libmathCommon.A.dylib
0x95598000 - 0x9573fff7  libSystem.B.dylib 125.2.1 (compatibility 1.0.0) <62291026-D016-705D-DC1E-FC2B09D47DE5> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x96675000 - 0x96695fe7  libresolv.9.dylib 41.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <751955F3-21FB-A03A-4E92-1F3D4EFB8C5B> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x96e34000 - 0x96ea3ff7  libvMisc.dylib 268.0.1 (compatibility 1.0.0) <5C3D7DA5-29EB-A745-E32B-26DBF547D532> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvMisc.dylib
0x98210000 - 0x982edff7  com.apple.vImage 4.0 (4.0) <64597E4B-F144-DBB3-F428-0EC3D9A1219E> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/vImage
0x991e6000 - 0x991f2ff7  libkxld.dylib ??? (???) <F0E915AD-6B32-0D5E-D24B-B188447FDD23> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0xffff0000 - 0xffff1fff  libSystem.B.dylib ??? (???) <62291026-D016-705D-DC1E-FC2B09D47DE5> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

Comment: A "darkened view" means you had a kernel panic.  Check your Console and check the logs for about the time the panic happened and see what's up.

Comment: I am looking at the logs there are STACKS of logs and error from my application - none of which have been show in Xcode console??!?!

Comment: Console is located in `/Applications/Utilities/Console`.  Select "All messages" and look through the messages during the time it happened.

Comment: Why do you want to delete this question?  @me back pls.

Comment: Because I have not received an answer to my question

Comment: OK so you have forced me now to mark this question as correct even though its incorrect.  These are the limitations you have imposed on us users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an Xcode/simulator issue.   THe "dark view" thing was a kernel panic, indicating something went horribly wrong in the OS.

This should be on superuser.

And they'd need to know more info:

- system configuration?  Model? Memory? Hard Drive?
- anything interesting in the console log?

Comment: This is LOADS of logs in the console but nothing in the Xcode console I would say at least 200 logs for today alone

Comment: @TheLearner The Xcode console has nothing to do with your system.  Don't look in there.  Look in `/Applications/Utilities/Console` like I said above.

Comment: Yeah but I am not concerned about my system I am concerned with my App because the app is logging loads of stuff see above

Comment: The messages you showed are crashes.  Look at "All Messages" or "Console Messages".  What is your system configuration?

Comment: If your system panic'd, you better had darned well be concerned about your system!  A Mac OS X system should *not* panic and, when it does so, it is quite often due to hardware issues.